# PrimeSense Carmine not working in ROS while kinect works

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a PrimeSense Carmine 1.09 and plugged in my laptop.
As I got kinect working before, I was really shocked that Carmine didn't work...
Is there any difference between the driver for kinect and Carmine?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66444/primesense-carmine-not-working-in-ros-while-kinect-works/) by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a try with the soon-to-come OpenNI2 support in ROS: [http://answers.ros.org/question/54747/primesense-carmine-doesnt-work-but-asus-xtion-does-openni-launch-devices-connected-but-not-found/?answer=66451#post-id-664511](http://answers.ros.org/question/54747/primesense-carmine-doesnt-work-but-asus-xtion-does-openni-launch-devices-connected-but-not-found/?answer=66451#post-id-66451)

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on 2013-07-03**:
Thanks! However do you have an idea when are they going to release?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-03**:
That's being worked on as we speak: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/issues/15

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-15**:
Both OpenNI2 camera & launch have been released. They are currently available only on the shadow-fixed repo. The next sync should bring them into public as well.